# Nuxt 2 page with dynamic params

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a dynamic link with path `/user/reset/{params1}/{params2}/{hash}/json`
And I created page in `/pages/user/reset/_slug.vue` , but in works only with 1 param.
How can I create page for this path?

Answer (score 2):

You could either have `/pages/user/reset/_param1/_param2/_hash.vue` (`param` are directories here)
or you could use `/pages/_.vue` with an [unkown dynamic nested route](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing#unknown-dynamic-nested-routes) but this may also catch some other routes, not sure if it's the desired behavior here.

Comment: Thanks for this solution.
1) I thought creating a lot of folders is not a good way
2) I tried to create _.vue, but this page for all unregistered paths

Comment: @ВадимГаджимурадов 1) if your structure requires it, I see no issue about creating a lot of folders per-se. 2) this may catch your route but probably not the best approach here.